# How to merge/fetch issues/pull requests from upstream to my fork

Tags: github

How to merge/fetch issues/pull requests from upstream to my fork ?

I want to apply PullRequest, but I'm not sure how can I fork the Pull-request from upstream ?

Or I need add requester repository ?

Comment: Did you managed to find the answer? What I thought is add remote to requester's repo too, but I doubt is there a easier way...

Comment: I managed that it's possible to `pull` or `rebase` from `remote` of requester's repo. I doubt about easier way too...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull requests from other forks into my fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork). The basic premise is to add a remote (`git remote add upstream https://github.com/otheruser/repo.git`) for the upstream repo. This gives you easy access to any commits (PRs, etc) from that repo