# How to git fetch and checkout without creating a remote branch locally?

Tags: git, merge, git-checkout, pull, git-fetch

Use Case: I have some repo on GitHub, someone forked it and added new feature and initiated pull request. 
I can't automatically merge it because there are some minor problems I would like to fix first.

It's one-time activity I'll never need this remote repository, so I don't want to create local `remote` branch.

Basically I would like to do:

1. copy files from remote repository and rewrite my own (without any git-related information).
2. see difference with my current head.
3. fix something and commit it.

How to do that?

`git checkout git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git` doesn't works at all (fail with error)

`git fetch git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git` works but doesn't update anything

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use `FETCH_HEAD`.

whenever you run `git fetch ...` a magic reference called `FETCH_HEAD` is created.

Try for example:

```
git fetch git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git branch_name && git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `git pull git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git` ?

Comment: @CiroSantilli华涌低端人口六四事件法轮功, yes, I think so.  This works well for me:

`git pull --no-commit git@github.com:<fork>/<repo>.git <branch>`

Answer (score 21):

For any Git server:

```
git fetch git://host.com/path/to/repo.git remote-branch-name:local-branch-name
git checkout local-branch-name
```

Answer (score 10):

Another neat method (at least on/from Github) is fetching like this:

```
git fetch repo pull/7324/head:pr-7324
```

Where:

`repo` points to the remote repo, e.g. `git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git`.

`pull/7324/head` is the remote pull request.

`pr-7324` is the local pull-request branch.

Then you can use the local PR branch to do whatever you want with it.

*Source*: adapted from [this discussion](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247).

Comment: Pull request checkout was discussed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743514/how-can-i-fetch-an-unmerged-pull-request-for-a-branch-i-dont-own