# How do I take a GitHub pull request and simply download that as a separate project?

Tags: git, github

Say I have [this pull request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55) and I want to download it as if it was its own separate project. How do I go about doing that? I don't see any button for that functionality.

Comment: Note the source of the pull request "mlwelles:master".
If you go to the user mlwelles's repos you will find https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client the master branch is where this code is.

Comment: Hmm. What if the user had hundreds of repos though? There's no simple "jump" button from the pull request page?

Comment: GitHub automatically names the repository so hopefully it will be named the same as the original just with a different user. They do allow changing the name after forking, it still indicates the main repo "MvvmCrossRenamed forked from MvvmCross/MvvmCross" on the "Repositories" tab.

Comment: No there isn't and that's why github pull requests are not as useful as the ones created by `git pull-request`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can download a snapshot of the tree at that commit over [here](https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client/archive/34501538a866d51f9ec5a486be8d34f8162ccf7f.zip). This is an exported tarball so you won't have any history. Is that what you're looking for? You can get to this by first looking at the [commits he wants you to pull](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55/commits) and then picking the [latest one in the list](https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client/commit/34501538a866d51f9ec5a486be8d34f8162ccf7f). Navigating to this URL will give you the diff (i.e. it's examining the commit object rather than actual tree). You can now simply change the `commit` in the above url to `tree` or click on the "Browse code" button. Once you do that, there's a "Download ZIP" button on the right which allows you to download the tree.

If you want complete history, then you need to fetch mlwelles changes. You can do this by going to the `mlwelles:master` repository over [here](https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client) and adding that as a remote to your own local clone using `git remote add mlwelles git@github.com:mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client.git`. Then you can fetch the changes he's asking you to merge using `git fetch remote master`. The changes will be available in `FETCH_HEAD`. You can either view them using `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` and `git log` (or whatever), view the diffs using `git diff FETCH_HEAD` (against your current branch) or finally integrate the changes he's asking you to using `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. Once you do this, you can push the changes to your own repository using `git push origin master` (assuming the original repository is added as `origin`).

Comment: How did you get to that? And yes, that's mostly what I wanted. But what if I simply had a copy of the main repo on my computer and wanted to merge the pull request from the command line? Is that possible? If so, do I merge it as a remote? If so (lots of if sos...) where do I get the remote's URL?

Comment: And the option to have history would be nice as well

Comment: Just updated the answer. I think it should be more useful to you now.

Comment: For me it seem to work, but with another URL:
https://github.com/sosedoff/pgweb/tree/pull/308/head - note that tree is located after the repo name, and head is given instead of the hash.

Answer (score 9):

In case you are just interested in a tar or zip archive, there is actually an [API for that](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link). You can use a link like the following to download the content of the pull request:

https://api.github.com/repos/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager/zipball/pull/55/head

The important part is that the part behind the /zipball/ (or /tarball/) must be a valid git reference. For pull requests this would be pull/*ID*/head there ID is the pull requests ID. See step 5 of [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/).

Comment: This is the closest I get, but this downloads the whole repo. How to download only the files which are part of the pull request itself?

Answer (score 6):

Did you check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request) already?

Will look something like this for Michael's pull request:

```
git clone https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client.git -b master
```

which ended up giving me a clone of Michael's pull request locally.