# Cloning a pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

How do I clone/pull a pull request to a local repository from Bitbucket? There is a  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947934/567555) for Github but I am somehow not able to find a handle to the pull request on Bitbucket that I can name on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer you're linking to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947934/1469208) *is not GitHub-specific*! You can do the same on Bitbucket. Simply go (on Bitbucket) to original repository (from where pull request originates):

[image]

And clone it (entire or selected branch) in current state, to check it, before merging that PR into your repository.