# How to clone/download code from a pull request

Tags: git, github

I found a source code in github. It has some pull request which indicates the changing code. I would like to download/clone one of them to my PC. Its pull request id is 3983 at the address https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3983
Thank all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Because, someone has more one pull request, each pull request has own ID. How can I download correct version which corresponds to pull request ID

It is better to clone the original repo, and import the [PR branch based on its ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622034/6309)

```
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe
cd caffe
git remote add christianpayer https://github.com/christianpayer/caffe.git
```

Then, for one of christianpayer's merged PR into origin:

```
git fetch origin pull/3983/head:pull_3983
git checkout pull_3983
```

You can fetch other PRs from that remote repo, or add other remote repos for fetching other PRs.

Comment: I tried your third command and I got the error "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref pull/3983/head
Unexpected end of command stream".

Comment: Yes, that is expected since the PR number exists only on origin repo: replace Christian payer by origin

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

**1**:

```
git clone https://github.com/christianpayer/caffe.git
cd caffe
git checkout nd-cudnn
```

It is from here:

https://github.com/christianpayer/caffe/tree/nd-cudnn

**2**:

`git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git`

`cd caffe/.git`

Now add the line `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to `config`

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Now fetch all the pull requests:

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:joyent/node
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/5190/head -> origin/pr/5190
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/5193/head -> origin/pr/5193
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/5198/head -> origin/pr/5198
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/520/head -> origin/pr/520

...
```

To check out a particular pull request:

```
$ git checkout pr/3983
Branch pr/3983 set up to track remote branch pr/3983 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'pr/3983'
```

Comment: What is git checkout nd-cudnn? Because I got the error when using it `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` Do I need go to caffe folder first?

Comment: You had to `cd` before that so I added `cd caffe`

Comment: Thanks. I also have a question. How do you know the `https://github.com/christianpayer/caffe.git` corresponding to pull request 3983?

Comment: christianpayer  wants to merge 32 commits into BVLC:master from christianpayer:nd-cudnn

he forked from main repo and filed PR from his forked repo

Comment: So, everyone want to make a pull request, he will have a forked version. We just go to his website and find it. Is it right? Because, someone has more one pull request, each pull request has own ID. How can I download correct version which corresponds to pull request ID

Comment: forking repository is not necessary, people can create their own branch also in the same repo. So best would be after `git checkout nd-cudnn` you look into `git log --oneline` and find the commit hash in which you are interested. You can see in PR what all commits he is merging.