# Clone a pull request for which no branch was created?

Tags: git, github

I can see [how to clone a pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request), but the answers rely on there being a specific branch made for the PR.

How do we clone a PR for which no branch was explicitly created; that is, a pull request that was created via the following workflow:

1. Fork original
2. Make changes, commit
3. Make pull request to original

(no explicit branching)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622034/1256452 (answer within the question you linked). Read the accepted answer, sure, but then read on! :-) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969986/1256452 has the same thing, more or less, plus an alias.)

Comment: @torek thanks really appreciate it. I think I understand it. Is `NEW_LOCAL_BRANCH` made up on the spot ie at the time of the clone? Eg `pull_611` in the linked example

Comment: Yes, `git fetch` will create it. (If you use an existing branch name, `git fetch` has rules it follows about updating branches, but generally you want to use a name based on the PR # so that the name is unique and the question never arises :) )

Answer (score 0):

Based on @torek's advice, simply

```
git fetch origin pull/4/head
```

where the `4` came from

[image]