# Native script angular android app error with nativescript-webrtc

Tags: angular, webrtc, nativescript

Getting error like :

Error executing Static Binding Generator: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.
Please change the name of one of the extended classes.
File:D:\BeHappy\Android App\BeHappy\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns\FragmentClass.java Class: com.tns.FragmentClass
Detailed log here: D:\BeHappy\Android App\BeHappy\platforms\android\build-tools\runSbg.log

Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

Package.json:
{
"name": "BeHappy",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
"@nativescript/angular": "^13.0.0",
"@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
"@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~10.0.1",
"nativescript-webrtc-plugin": "^2.0.0-alpha.22",
"rxjs": "~7.4.0",
"tns-core-modules": "^6.5.27",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
"@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
"@nativescript/types": "~8.1.1",
"@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "~13.1.1",
"typescript": "~4.4.4"
}
}

Other versions I am using as:
TNS : 8.1
gradle : 6.4
jdk - 1.8

Comment: Why is there `tns-core-modules` in the Package.json?
Remove `tns-core-modules` from Package.json and remove `node_module` after that run `ns clean` and `npm i`. Then try to start the project again. Maybe it's help

Comment: Thanks miladfm. if I remove package tns-core-module I am getting below error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-webrtc-plugin/src/android/TNSRTCMediaDevices.js 3:10-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/application' in 'D:\BeHappy\Android App\BeHappy\node_modules\nativescript-webrtc-plugin\src\android'

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `nativescript-webrtc` plugin is not update. There are some banking change in NativeScript 7 and the Author of plugin has to update it and the last update from `nativescript-webrtc` was for 3 years ago.

Somebody has already updated to ns7/8, but the author didn't merge it with master branch. (https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc/pull/61)

To fix that, you can do the following steps:

1. Clone the `nativescript-webrtc` repository
2. Merge the PR with master branch in your local system (see this link to how you can do that: [GitHub clone from pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request))
3. Run `npm run build` in clone repository
4. Run `tns plugin remove nativescript-webrtc-plugin` in your NativeScript project
5. Run `tns clean` in your NativeScript project
6. Remove `node_module` folder from your NativeScript project
7. Run `npm i` in your NativeScript project
8. Run `tns plugin add [RELATIVE PATH TO CLONE REPO]` in your NativeScript project (for example: `tns plugin add ./plugins/nativescript-webrtc-plugin`)
9. Make sure `nativescript-webrtc-plugin` in `package.json` from NativeScript project pointed to your local system.

```
{
   ...
   "dependencies": {
    ...
    "nativescript-webrtc-plugin": "./plugins/nativescript-webrtc-plugin",
    ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Now you can run your project again

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I tried cloning the repo but getting auth error as

$ git fetch git@github.com:triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc.git refs/pull/61/head
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: It's because SSH Authentication, try to clone the repository with HTTPS (`git clone https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc.git`)

Comment: Hi @miladfm, i follow your steps on cloning #61 pr into my local and then npm run build. But i got a lots of TS errors such as error TS1110: Type expected, error TS1005: '}' expected, error TS1005: ';' expected. Any ideas what is causing this?