# How do I download GitHub pull request?

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-for-windows

here is the pull request I would like https://github.com/OpenKore/openkore/pull/3802/files
I want to download like it as its own separate project. How do I go about doing that? I don't see any button for that functionality

but I have no idea how to get the entire project from that commit...
Can someone please tell me how to do this?
btw im on windows
How can I download github "pull requests" files? thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub clone from pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request)

Comment: What using the code button at top of the page

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps in your terminal:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:OpenKore/openkore.git
cd openkore
git fetch origin --prune
git checkout -b bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster origin/bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster
git status
```

Here's the explanation:

1. `git clone git@github.com:OpenKore/openkore.git`: clone the project from remote to local, you don't need to do so if you have done it already.
2. `cd openkore`: enter the folder of this project.
3. `git fetch origin --prune`: check all the updates in the remote repo.
4. `git checkout -b bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster origin/bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster`: create a local branch `bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster` and link it to the remote branch `origin/bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster`, which refers to the pull request you mentioned. The name of local branch `bugfix/remove-processcheckmonster` can be changed to any name you like.
5. `git status`: check whether you are on the correct branch, according your question, it should show something like this:
   [image]
6. Now you have downloaded the branch of the pull request you want.