# Deleted remote origin, pull request doesn't recognize my pushed commits

Tags: git, github

**The Problem:**

I created a pull request from a forked repo. I deleted my fork yesterday and now when I commit to the upstream, the upstream doesn't add the commit to the Pull Request discussion/history where the code is being reviewed. The commit did go through and is on the upstream, but wasn't added to the Pull Request commit history.

**How I created the problem:**

- Made a Pull Request, the PR was in the process of review and I added a few changes.
- I deleted the forked version of the repository.  The remotes were:

  - name.myaccount origin master
  - name.owners account upstream master
- I re-forked the repository and the remotes are set up the same way.
- When I pushed a new commit to the upstream, it went through and the upstream has the commit in the proper branch the PR is located.
- The commit wasn't added to the PR discussion or detected even though it is there.

Any ideas on how I can get github to recognize my commits in the pull request?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: Create new pull request from new fork.

Comment: @PetSerAl would this delete or not merge with the current pull request comment history?

Comment: @HelloWorld It would be new separate pull request. You can close old one and add link to new.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover a commit sent as a pull-request from a deleted fork on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977530/recover-a-commit-sent-as-a-pull-request-from-a-deleted-fork-on-github)