# Recover git deleted pull request

Tags: git, github, git-history

About a year ago, pull-requests for the release of some developments were created on a project I'm working on.

After a few months they were canceled on the advice of the management of the company for which we are developing.

Now we need to recover those developments.

Is there a way to recover deleted pull-requests in git? If yes, what procedure should I follow?
Thank you,

Simone

Comment: You are talking about "pull requests", which could indicate that your central repository is hosted on github. Is that correct ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977530/recover-a-commit-sent-as-a-pull-request-from-a-deleted-fork-on-github

Comment: @LeGEC yes. Correct

Comment: yes, those pull request must be present in closed pull requests section in github

Comment: Click on `Pull Request` --> select closed , Here you will get all the closed PR links

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover a commit sent as a pull-request from a deleted fork on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977530/recover-a-commit-sent-as-a-pull-request-from-a-deleted-fork-on-github)

Comment: except that you don't need to create a fork of the root repository

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue clicking on Pull Request --> select closed , Here you will get all the closed PR links.

Thanks,

Simone