# Can I pull a not-yet-merged pull request?

Tags: git, github

Example: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1731

Sometimes I need to pull this kind of pull requests because I open an issue, and someone else provides a fix. Then the project collaborator may ask me to verify whether the fix works before his merging. So how to pull these pull requests instead of manually doing changes to my local repository?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can [fetch pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)

```
git fetch origin pull/1731/head:shelhamer-cudnn-r2
git checkout shelhamer-cudnn-r2
```

and after testing, go back to `master`.