# Merge and Maintain Node module with an unmerged pull request

Tags: git, reactjs, react-native

I have this library that I would like to use:

https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-image-carousell

But as it stands it has not been updated and is no longer working with RN 0.30. A user has submitted a pull request but the owner has to merge it. How can I grab this pull request into my node_modules?

EDIT: To those saying that this is a duplicate of [How can I fetch an unmerged pull request for a branch I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743514/how-can-i-fetch-an-unmerged-pull-request-for-a-branch-i-dont-own), I'm mostly wondering what's the best way to do this and maintain the project with it being in node_modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-native-image-carousell` is MIT licensed so just publish your own version of it to the npm registry

- fork the `react-native-image-carousell` repo
- merge the outstanding pull request
- publish your own version to the npm registry
- `npm install my-own-react-native-image-carousel`

Comment: `npm` supports GitHub urls natively, so you don't even need to publish. Just `npm install youruser/react-native-image-carousell` and it's pulled from GitHub. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of react-native-image-carousell. Sorry for late to publish the new version with RN 0.30 support.
Here is it react-native-image-carousell@0.1.3
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-carousell.

Please free free to open an issue to me if you have any further questions.
Thank you.