# How squash and merge a Pull Request with GPG signing via command line?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, gpg-signature

https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits

Is there way to squash and merge a Pull Request with my GPG signing via command line? Merging a Pull Request on UI doesn't supports GPG signing. I've tried to merge via `git merge --squash`, but it doesn't close the Pull Request automatically.

Answer (score 15):

The "[Squash and merge your pull request commits](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits)" is a server-side option which, indeed, does not support gpg signing.

That means you need to:

- [fetch the pull request in a local clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9903203/6309)
- `git merge --squash`, with the [`--gpg-sign` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge--Sltkeyidgt)
- push the new merge commit
- use the GitHub API to [update the Pull Request state](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request) or [manually close the pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-a-pull-request/).

It is a manual and somewhat convoluted process, but it will work.

Comment: Will this only show the key for the person merging or will it also show the original keys?

Comment: @AlexisTyler The merge commit should show your key (with a "verified", as shown in https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/)

Comment: all good. Just wanted to clarify for the answer since you didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [hub command line tool](https://hub.github.com).

The command is `hub merge <url-to-pull-request>`.

If you have authentication issues, you can use a developer token instead of password.