# GitHub: How to add open pull requests to local repo?

Tags: git, github

I'm using the [NSDate-Extensions](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions) plugin in my iOS Xcode project. The master repo has some errors which seems to be fixed in two Pull Requests:

- https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/pull/6
- https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/pull/7

These requests are still open and not accepted to the master repo. How can I add these to my local repo in a Git-way? It would be fine, if my local repo gets update, if their Fork gets updated later:

- https://github.com/Ricardo1980/NSDate-Extensions
- https://github.com/exalted/NSDate-Extensions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull requests from other forks into my fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: how can i fetch an unmerged pull request for a branch i don't own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743514/git-how-can-i-fetch-an-unmerged-pull-request-for-a-branch-i-dont-own)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a `.patch` to the end of the pull url - you can download and apply the patch on your repo:

```
curl https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/pull/6.patch | git am
```

Comment: After I've done the above command, the patch applied successfully, but when I'm running a `git status` it says that there isn't any changes. Why can this patch change my local repo and still say that there isn't any changes?

Comment: @manojlds: nice trick! your answer also applies to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork

Comment: @DennisMadsen: `git am` doesn't *not* just apply the patch. pull/*.patch is actually multiple patches (one per commit in the pull request) And each patch is applied as commit. So after that there are no uncommited changes (which git status could display).

Comment: This only works with simple pull request that never merged commits from master. For that reason I would always prefer using the actual pull request branches as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096344/1904815.

Comment: Looks like something has changed at GitHub. That url is just a redirect/link to `https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/erica/NSDate-Extensions/pull/6.patch`. Substituting the new url works, though.

Comment: @Sparhack @dhrm You can use `curl -L` to follow redirects if you prefer the old URL format.

Answer (score 21):

You can pull the requests from the command line without adding remotes:

```
git pull https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions +refs/pull/6/head
```

If you are not already sure you want to do that, then you might want to check out that branch first with:

```
git fetch https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions +refs/pull/6/head:refs/origin/pull/6
```

The advantage of this compared to using the patch files is that git gets the actual commits. So git can see when master was previously merged into the pull request. The patch file is completely unaware of such differences.

Answer (score 12):

You should add the forks that offered the pull requests, and add them as a remote:

- Find the person contributing the link (normally just click the sha1 hash)
- Do something like:

  ```
  git remote add githubuser theirgithubfork.git
  ```

Then you can easily pull down their changes:

- ```
  git fetch githubuser
  ```

Easily take individual commits with"

- ```
  git cherry-pick thesha1fromthepullrequest
  ```

For a complete example, imagine [this pull request (`6bbbcc5`) from *RogerE* on the Ruby Capistrano project](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/142).

```
$ git clone git@github.com:capistrano/capistrano.git
$ cd capistrano
$ git remote add RogerE https://github.com/RogerE/capistrano.git
$ git fetch RogerE
$ git cherry-pick 6bbbcc5
```

Comment: So I should clone the original repo from erica, and run "git remote add" for both the forks by Ricardo1980 and exalted? What if I afterwards make a "git pull", would it just pull from the original repo -- or would updates from the two remotes gets pulled too?

Comment: Why are you both making a fetch and afterwards a cherry-pick? Wouldn't the fetch pull down all from the remote?

Comment: `git pull` would pull from the original repo. You could specify which repo to pull from by specifying the remote name and the refspec. e.g. `git pull RogerE master`.

Comment: `git fetch` would just download the changes but won't actually merge it yet until you specify a command to merge them e.g. `git merge` or `git rebase`.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way using a single pull command to get updates from the three repos at once?

Comment: No, you have to add each repository you want to take the changes from as a remote, `fetch` them all (download commits). And then `cherry-pick` the commits that you want. Cherry-picking preserves the authorship of the commits, and the `SHA1` hash. If the `origin` repository ever does pull them into master, there's no problems with merge conflicts if you work this way.

Comment: When you make `git pull` that actually (by default) expands to `git pull origin master`. In your example your `origin` remote is `erica`. So when you make `git pull` you pull the master branch from `erica`. The remotes are not involved at all. This is by design.

Answer (score -3):

You can pull specific pull requests like this:

```
git pull https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/pull/6
git pull https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/pull/7
```

imo this is much easier than adding a remote (especially when it is just one-off fixes) or piping via curl.

Comment: The idea is correct, but it doesn't work like that, which is possibly the reason for the downvote. I added a working answer with the same idea at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096344/1904815)