# Can I pull merge request submitted not to me but the main repo?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pull requests from other forks into my fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)

I have forked a repo on Github and have made some changes which suits me. I then noticed a lot of pending Merge Requests on the main repo from which I had forked. I would like some of them on my repo.

Now my question is. Is it possible for me to somehow pull those changes into my fork?

Comment: looks like @charlesB suggested correct, the soln hangs out thr..

Comment: Yup it is a duplicate. Please close this.