# Is it possible to accept pull request from a cloned/forked repo?

Tags: git, github, fork, pull-request, git-am

Is it possible to accept pull request from a cloned repo?

Example ( fork of repo ):

- Repo #1: https://github.com/acme/original_project
- Repo #2: https://github.com/blah/original_project ( fork )

Pull Request Limbo:

- Repo #1 has new pull request but does not accept/merge
- Repo #2 wants the new pull request from Repo #1

Is there any way to accept the pull request from Repo #1 to Repo #2?

Does this make sense? Maybe a git upstream pull request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull requests from other forks into my fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pull request applied to Repo #1 comes from a fork(another repository). If Repo #2 would like to apply the pull request, it's as simple as adding the fork as a remote and then fetch the changes directly from that fork.

See https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo and https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests, which actually explain this in much more detail.

Another approach would be to directly apply the patch by using `git am`. There is an example of `git am` in usage in the latter link.

Comment: Great! But since I'm new to git where would I find some documentation on this process? Example? I'm coming from SVN but things are starting to come together

Comment: I've added a link to the GitHub documentation for forking a repository and managing pull requests.