# How do I download files that are in a pull request, from github?

Tags: github, ubuntu-12.04, pull-request

I am trying to download these files that are in a pull request: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/1653

Is this possible through linux terminal using git clone?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull requests from other forks into my fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)