# How to get interesting commits from my git repo's forks into my repo?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Let's say my github repo X has a lot of forks, and some of them have really good new features (=commits). Afaik without a pull/merge request from the fork's owner it's not possible to "get" those commits into my repo (but this is not what i want. i want to pick the stuff i need, not getting requests from other users).

So my question is: How to get commits **from my repo's forks** into my repo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that these commits aren't in pull requests don't prevent you to apply them to your fork. You can simply add these fork as remotes to your repo, and cherry-pick/rebase/merge (choose the right one) commits from them. So it's just:

```
git remote add nice-fork https://github.com/author/repo
git fetch nice-fork
#then the remote branches and commits are imported in your repo.
```

If the commits you want are in pull requests, [you can also get them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022302/11343).

Comment: But from that point we still don't have the commit. A `cherry-pick` is needed now...