# How can I merge open Github pull requests into a fork?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge, pull-request

This popular [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) repository has 30+ open pull requests.

Can I merge them into a [fork](https://github.com/dmitriz/stream-handbook)?

What would be the easiest way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply unmerged upstream pull requests from other forks into my fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/how-to-apply-unmerged-upstream-pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you will have to do this manually, one PR at a time. https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Comment: Thank you, very helpful link, `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` is what I've been looking for.